# Calculate field value based on lat long. Have longitude values which are negative?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator, syntax

Very new to python, fairly experienced with ArcMap. I am trying to create an alphanumeric index based on point locations

My code string for the numeric part is here:

```
def calc(!LONG_x!):

    if !LONG_x! >= -113.90550 and !LONG_x! <= -113.90559:
        return "05"
    else:
        return "0"
```

I continue to get an error 000989 for syntax. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use punctuation marks in variable names in python. Your function should probably read more like this:

```
def calc(LONG_x):
    if LONG_x >= -113.90550 and LONG_x <= -113.90559:
        return "05"
    else:
        return "0"
```

You can then pass in !LONG_x! as an argument to the function.

eg. result = calc(!LONG_x!)

Comment: BruceDoh, That solved it. Thank you. I have Magnus Hetland's beginning python book. Does one find these syntax answers somewhere within its pages?

Comment: Right, I think the !FieldName! notation is specific to ArcGIS and isn't strictly Python proper. Magnus probably says somewhere in the book that variable names can only have letters, numbers, and underscores (no special characters) and can't begin with a number.

Comment: When solved, it is good idea to mark it as solved

Comment: And how do I mark it as solved?

Comment: Click the checkmark button under the up and down arrows.

Comment: Ooops! I had an ad blocker running which was blocking the arrows. All marked now.